# How can I pass the contents of a pem file in the scp command?

Tags: linux, bash

Just wondering if this is at all possible to run the scp command like:

```
scp [flag] "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc..." user:website.com@/path/to/file ./
```

Comment: That related SO question should be informative, since `scp` uses the same flag as `ssh` to specify a keyfile. There may be a way, but it does not seem like a recommended approach for security purposes.

Comment: Thanks for linking the question for me. I was racking my brains googling trying to find if this is at all possible. I agree its not the recommended way of doing it. I was just seeing if it would be a possible solution.

Comment: I think it's worthwhile to explore these questions. In this case it's clearly not a good idea for security purposes but that's why we ask questions—to discover and learn :)